# SQL Statements Display More Rows Than Table Has

Tags: sql, oracle

So I've just come across something interesting, and I don't know if it's been answered before, as I have no clue what it's called. Lets say that you have two tables; the first has one row and the second has two rows. If you run the following statment:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
```

it returns two rows, and both have the same value, but the first table only has one row! Why does this occur? I didn't think having another table in the from clause changed anything if you didn't change the select clause accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are selecting a [**cartesian product**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two tables.

It will return `COUNT(t1) * COUNT(t2)` records: all possible combinations of records from `t1` with records from `t2`.

Using `ANSI` syntax, your query would read as:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM    table1 t1
CROSS JOIN
        table2 t2
```

Comment: And here, I thought I discovered something cool. Thanks for the quick reply and clearing up my confusion!